# How to calculate correlation between two functions in Python

Tags: python, r, correlation

I need to calculate the correlation of two functions in Python

In R, I'd do:

```
g = function(x) {exp(-0.326723067*x)*cos(0.36002998837*x)}
f = function(x) {-x+1}

cor(f(u),g(u))
```

What would be the equivalent way in Python? I think I'd need to evaluate the function first before calculate the correlation. Is that so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want `Pearson's correlation`. If so:

Using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
np.corrcoef(f(u), g(u))
```

Using `scipy`:

```
import scipy.stats
scipy.stats.pearsonr(f(u), g(u))
```

Using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
f(u).corr(g(u)) # or
g(u).corr(f(u))
```

Using `pingouin`:

```
import pingouin as pg
pg.corr(f(u), g(u))
```